# sync SharePoint 2016 On- Premesis with new OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

When i try to sync SharePoint document library with new OneDrive client it is not working it is still connecting to the old OneDrive client.
We have installed the new OneDrive client but still SharePoint looking for old client.
For Online SharePoint there is an option in the admin center --> Start the new client.
But for On-Premises SharePoint where we can set this up?
Is it possible to sync SharePoint 2016 On- Premesis with new OneDrive?
SharePoint On-Premises 2016 how i can sync document libraries with new one drive client?

Regards
Sajeev[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fU4l.png)

Answer (score 0):

There were several improvements and fixes introduced in the latest PU (public update) to SharePoint 2016 on-premises that include OneDrive APIs and SharePoint framework (SPx) new features and enhancements. If possible, try to update/upgrade first, then determine implementation feasibility. [March 2018 latest updates]